# Peeking a MSMQ outgoing queue with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, msmq

I am trying to peek an outgoing private queue with Powershell.  It doesn't have to be "pure" powershell, it can be wrapped .net code - I just don't know how to do that, so please make it something I can run in a powershell script.

I can successfully query a normal private queue:

```
$msmq = Get-MsmqQueue -Name "myqueuename" 

$var = Receive-MsmqQueue -input $msmq -Peek -Count 5000 -Timeout 5000 -RetrieveBody
```

However, getting the details from an outgoingqueue are different.  Instead of get-msmqqueue, you have to use Get-MsmqOutgoingQueue, but that doesn't work with receive-msmqqueue:

```
> Receive-MsmqQueue -input $msmq -Peek 

Receive-MsmqQueue : Cannot bind parameter 'InputObject'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.OutgoingQueue" value of type 
"Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.OutgoingQueue" to type "Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.MessageQueue".
At line:1 char:26
+ Receive-MsmqQueue -input $msmq -Peek
+                          ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Receive-MsmqQueue], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Msmq.PowerShell.Commands.ReceiveMSMQQueueCommand
```

[A different Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440897/peeking-an-msmq-outgoing-queue-with-jscript) said:

> Outgoing Queues are not real Queues, but can be seen as a "list of
>   messages, grouped by the Queue they are destined to".

However, I have no idea how you'd get the general "list of messages" it refers to.

Any help greatly appreciated!